# Could not find driver pdo-mysql laravel homestead

Tags: mysql, laravel, pdo

I am running a database migration on laravel homestead and I am getting a could not find driver error

running the following command: php artisan migrate

my pdo-mysql.so is enabled in my PHP.ini

When I install laravel homestead there are 4 different version of php 5.6 7.1 7.2 7.3

The phpinfo says it's using 7.3

```
php artisan migrate

Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL: select 
* from information_schema.tables where table_schema = sim and table_name 
= migrations)

at C:\laravel- 
projects\sim\vendor\laravel\framework\src\
Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664
660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, 
we'll format the error
661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make 
this exception a
662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the 
database's errors.
663|         catch (Exception $e) {
664|             throw new QueryException(
665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
666|             );
667|         }
668|

Exception trace:

1   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("could not find driver")
  C:\laravel-projects\sim\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\
Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php:31

2   PDOException::("could not find driver")
  C:\laravel-projects\sim\vendor\doctrine\dbal
\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php:27
```

Comment: Try a `>php --ini` and see which ini file PHP is loading. Then check the extension is activated in that ini file. As often there is a seperate php.ini file for the web server and the CLI

Comment: stated that the php.ini file is located in  /etc/php/7.3/cli/. I uncommented the pdo driver and I ran the following command
vagrant reload --provision

I am getting the following error:

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_mysql (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_allocator)) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Solved the problem. The CLI is not on the ubuntu server that you need to amend but on the windows environment